# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar la fila con menor suma de la matriz?

Tags: c++, matriz

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
        int opc;
        cout<<"SELECCIONE UNA OPCION";
        cout<<"\n1.- Matriz 3x4";
        cout<<"\n2.- Arreglo unidimensional";
        cout<<"\n3.- Ordenamiento";
        cout<<"\n4.- Moda, media y mediana";
        cout<<"\n5.- Salir";
        cout<<"\n\nTeclee un opcion: ";

        cin>>opc;

        switch(opc){        case 1: 
            int menor;
            int array[3];
            int array2[1];
            int matriz[3][4];
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                    cout<<"\nIngrese un numero para la posicion ["
                        <<i<<"] ["<<j<<"]: ";
                    cin>>matriz[i][j];
                }
            }
            cout<<"\nLa matriz ingresada es la siguiente:\n "<<endl;
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                    cout<<"\t"<<matriz[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
            //Suma de cada fila
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                array[i]=0;
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                    array[i]=array[i]+matriz[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, desarrolla un poco la pregunta añadiendo algo de texto. Añade un contexto y explica cual es el problema que estás teniendo

Comment: Ya que tienes un bucle que va iterando por las filas para calcular su suma, puedes aprovechar ese mismo bucle para actualizar el mínimo encontrado hasta ese momento. Para ello tienes una variable llamada `minimo` que inicializas con un valor muy alto (por ejemplo `INT_MAX`) y lo vas comparndo con lo que te ha salido en cada fila, actualizándolo si el de la fila es menor. Si lo necesitas puedes tener otra variable para guardar en qué índice de fila apareció el menor hasta ese momento. Al terminar el bucle tendrás la respuesta.

Comment: El código compila y se ejecuta ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente?